# How to display a list of checkbox basing on a DropDownList using Script in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a view 'Application' which contain a DropDownList and a Table.

The items of DropDownList are being loaded from the base (Table=Genre) in form of a list.

According to the selected item in the DropDownList, I want didplay some values (list) in the base in form of CheckBox in the table.

I tried CheckBoxFor but it's not working.

This is the View :

```
<div>
         <%:Html.Label("Type :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGenre, Model.GenreItems)%>

   </div>

   <table border = "transparent">
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>

        </tr>

        <% foreach (var item in Model.FaItems) { %>
    <tr>
         <td>

            <%: Html:CheckBoxFor (modelItem => item.Nom_Famille) %>
        </td>


    </tr>
     <% } %>

    </table>
```

and this is the Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Application(Genre genre)
        {
            var vv = new FlowViewModel();

            vv.GenreItems = new SelectList(db.Genres.ToList(), "ID_G", "ID_G");


            if (vv.SelectedGenre == "Famille")
            {

                vv.FaItems = db.Familles.ToList();


            }
            else if (vv.SelectedGenre == "Sous Famille")
            {
                vv.SFItems = db.Sous_Familles.ToList();

            }
            return View(vv);

        }
```

and this is the model :

```
public class FlowViewModel
{

    [Key]
    public string IDv { get; set; }

    public List<Famille> FaItems { get; set; }
    public List<Sous_Famille> SFItems { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public SelectList GenreItems { get; set; }
    public string SelectedGenre { get; set; } 

    public FlowViewModel()
    {
        FaItems = new List<Famille>();
        SFItems = new List<Sous_Famille>();
    }
}
```

I tried to add this script to my view, but I didn't get any result :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post("/ProfileGa/Application", { term: "" + $("#Txt").val() + "SelectedGenre" }, 
function (html)
{
//construct check boxes with this data elements.
  $('#resultDiv').append("<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox" + html[i].Id + "'" + "/>" + html[i].title);
}
</script>
```